# Different outputs in Python

Tags: python

I want to delete strings("324a" included) and leave only integers in a list. Here is the code;

```
a = ["345", "sadas", "324a", "14", "john"]
    

for i in a:
    try:
        if i == int(i):
            continue
    except ValueError:
        a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

With this code the output is;

```
['345', '324a', '14']
```

Even tho "324a" is not an integer and code should return ValueError the code still does not remove it from the list.

---

Here is another simple code that shows "324a" is not a integer;

```
a = "324a"
a = int(a)
print(a)
```

Output of the code above;

```
a = int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '324a'
```

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: BTW, that whole if-statement is not needed and doesn't really make sense either. You can just use `int(i)`.

Comment: Also BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with you mutating the list while iterating over it.

Look at the code below and watch the printed index...you remove `sadas` at index 1 which now leaves `324a` at index 1, but the loop doesn't recognize the value change and thus does not repeat index 1 twice during the iteration.

```
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    print(idx)
    try:
        if i == int(i):
            continue
    except ValueError:
        a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

try -

```
a = ["345", "sadas", "324a", "14", "john"]
b = []
for i in a:
    try:
        int(i)
        b.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(b)
```

Comment: Yes, removing from list while iterating over it causes the problem. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

```
mixed_array = ["345", "sadas", "324a", "14", "john"]
only_integers= [] 

# A method to check if an object is integer
def is_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# Add integer objects from mixed_array to only_integers like:
only_integers = [i for i in mixed_array if is_int(i)]

# OR like:

only_integers = list(filter(is_int, mixed_array ))
```

Comment: I like this, but there's a few things that could be improved: 1) Use an else-clause to keep the try-clause as small as possible. 2) Don't use UpperCamelCase for function names, use snake_case or at least lowerCamelCase. 3) `isInt` is unnecesary when you can test the function result directly. 4) It's a bit simpler to use a comprehension or filter instead of a loop. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/3fcc8bba2851393aa4467697ea614fb4) with the changes.

Comment: Nice! Also I forgot to mention, it would help to add a short explanation of how the code works, like just a sentence or two.

Answer (score 0):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't remove items from a list while iterating through it.
Also, when `i` is a `str` following statement will be `False`: `i == int(i)`.
I suggest using this instead:

```
a = ["345", "sadas", "324a", "14", "john"]
tempList = []
for i in a:
    try:
        int(i)
        tempList.append(i) # if int(i) fails, this line won't be reached
    except ValueError:
        pass

a = tempList[:] # we use [:] to copy the list
print(a)
```

or this one-liner:

```
a = ["345", "sadas", "324a", "14", "john"]
print([int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()])
```

Comment: I can remove items from a list while iterating but this process messes the index. Here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the list you are iterating. Create a new one instead like this:

```
a = list(filter(None, map(lambda x: x if x.isdigit() else None, a)))
```

Edit: From the comment, we can directly use `str.isdigit` with `filter`,

```
a = list(filter(str.isdigit, a)))
```

Comment: That's a long way to say `list(filter(str.isdigit, a))`

Comment: Oh yes, `filter` can of-course directly accept `str.isdigit` as its argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple list comprehension like this:

```
a = [word for word in a if word.isdigit()]
```

And this will create a list with all the numbers.